# Looking for Azure Storage Queues alternative

Tags: azure, queue, message-queue

I have a client who needs an enterprise-deployed queuing service that functions much like the Azure Storage Queues, especially in terms of having a REST-front-end and an idempotent design.

It was fairly easy to develop my own queuing service, with a REST endpoint and Put / Get / Delete functionality, but now that I've crafted the code I'm starting to balk a bit.  Queuing will be a critical service for my client's apps, so I'd much prefer to leverage something that's a bit more time tested.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Azure Service Bus?  It is more "enterprisy", has a number of additional features that Storage queues do not support, like multi-subscriber support, broadcasts, etc and has a REST interface.
Pricing is very reasonable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee732537.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh780717.aspx